# Some weird behavior when extending a list in Python

Tags: python, list, extend

I wonder why the following Python code

```
aa = []
for x in range(5):
    bb = aa
    print(bb)
    bb.extend(['a','bb'])
    print(bb)
```

results in this:

```
[]
['a', 'bb']
['a', 'bb']
['a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb']
['a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb']
['a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb']
['a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb']
['a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb']
['a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb']
['a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb', 'a', 'bb']
```

Doesn't the third line `bb = aa` reset `bb` to the value of `aa` which is  `[]`? Why is `aa` also extended when `extend` was only applied to `bb`?

Does this mean that `bb = aa` is not creating a copy of `aa` in `bb` but instead only referencing `aa`? How should I create a copy of `aa` that is not a reference to `aa`?

Comment: exactly, it is not creating a copy, just referencing.

Comment: To make a copy you can do ```bb = [*aa]```